# Encoded query not working when using it to find data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am encoding a query with encodeURIComponent and then using it in backend but it isn't working.

Db : mongodb
Odm : mongoose

What i do is :

```
encodeURIComponent("{ name: { $regex: 'da', $options: 'i' }}")
which is %7B%20name%3A%20%7B%20%24regex%3A%20'da'%2C%20%24options%3A%20'i'%20%7D%7D
```

I send it like this:

```
/api/nft/search?q=%7B%20name%3A%20%7B%20%24regex%3A%20%27da%27%2C%20%24options%3A%20%27i%27%20%7D%7D
```

I use it like this :

```
exports.searchNftByName = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query.q);
  Nft.find(req.query.q).exec((err, nft) => {
    if (err || !nft) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        status: 'fail',
        message: 'NFT not found!',
      });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      message: 'We found something',
      nft,
    });
  });
};
```

`console.log(req.query.q);` out is  `{ name: { $regex: 'da', $options: 'i' }}`

When i copy it from console and use it directly to find the data it works.

Comment: It could be because the value in ```req.query.q``` could be in string format.Try console.log(typeof(req.query.q)) and check?

Comment: @fractal397 You are right it is string , i tried JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) but it gives me string

Comment: Your initial JSON string should be formatted as: ` '{ "a": 10 }'`. This can be parsed to a JS object and used in your query.